# I wonder if model.tar.gz from Sagemaker can be used for inference in another notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, xgboost, jupyter-lab, amazon-sagemaker

Little background: I successfully ran a regression experiment on AWS and saved the best model from that experiment. I have downloaded my best model as `model.tar.gz.` to use it for inference on my dataset elsewhere. I extracted it and uploaded the 'xgboost-model' file into my Jupyter Lab workspace, where my dataset is.

`regression_model = 'xgboost-model'`

`predictions = regression_model.predict(X_test)`

The error I'm getting is:

```
----> 1 predictions = regression_model.predict(X_test)

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'predict'
```

I know that `XGBRegressor` has `predict` attribute, but my model doesn't seem to have it though it's exported as an `xgboost` model. Any suggesstions on what I'm supposed to be doing instead?

Answer (score 0):

Hey so for your model data, you can use it in another notebook, but you need to make sure the dataset you're predicting on has the same attributes as the data you trained on so that you can predict accurately with the model. Second point to try out is using the boto3 invoke_endpoint call, the predict attribute is from the SageMaker Python SDK. The boto3 SDK is the general AWS Python SDK. I've attached an example of deploying your endpoint with this model.tar.gz, simply passing in the string is not adequate you need to create an endpoint and then perform inference with either the predict call or the invoke_endpoint call.

Example: https://github.com/RamVegiraju/Pre-Trained-Sklearn-SageMaker

Comment: That does it, much appreciated...